# Sympy: how to print a list of expressions all LaTeX typeset?

Tags: list, printing, jupyter, sympy, typeset

I have a list of polynomial expressions, (in my case obtained as the output of a Groebner basis computation), that I would like to view.  I am using Jupyter, and I have started off with

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()
```

This causes an individual expression to be given nicely typeset.  For a non-Groebner example:

```
sy.var('x')
fs = sy.factor_list(x**99-1)
fs2 = [x[0] for x in fs[1]]
fs2
```

The result is a nice list of LaTeX-typeset expressions.  But how do I print these expressions one at a time; or rather; one per line?  I've tried:

```
for f in fs2:
    sy.pprint(f)
```

but this produces ascii pretty printing, not LaTeX.  In general the expressions I have tend to be long, and I really do want to look at them individually.  I can of course do

```
fs2[0]
fs2[1]
fs2[2]
```

and so on, but this is tiresome, and hardly useful for a long list.  Any ideas or advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter (through IPython) has a convenience function called `display` which works well with SymPy:

```py
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()
sy.var('x')
fs = sy.factor_list(x**99-1)
fs2 = [x[0] for x in fs[1]]
for f in fs2:
    display(f)
```

Output:

[image]

You can also get the latex code for each of these polynomials by using the `latex` function:

```py
import sympy as sy
from sympy.printing.latex import latex
sy.init_printing()
sy.var('x')
fs = sy.factor_list(x**99-1)
fs2 = [x[0] for x in fs[1]]
for f in fs2:
    print(latex(f))
```

Output:

```
x - 1
x^{2} + x + 1
x^{6} + x^{3} + 1
x^{10} + x^{9} + x^{8} + x^{7} + x^{6} + x^{5} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1
x^{20} - x^{19} + x^{17} - x^{16} + x^{14} - x^{13} + x^{11} - x^{10} + x^{9} - x^{7} + x^{6} - x^{4} + x^{3} - x + 1
x^{60} - x^{57} + x^{51} - x^{48} + x^{42} - x^{39} + x^{33} - x^{30} + x^{27} - x^{21} + x^{18} - x^{12} + x^{9} - x^{3} + 1
```

Comment: Oh yes!  Many thanks indeed.  I thought I’d tried "display" but apparently not.  Anyway, it works a treat.

Comment: Should it be `from IPython.display import display` first?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In Jupyter `display` is available by default, but outside of Jupyter yes, that import is required.